# How do you make the HTML tags into normal text

Tags: html

HTML code is in tags for example the body tag is inside <>. I want to make a tutorial about the body tags but they won't show cuz HTML thought it is just a tag. How can I fix it?
Here is a simplified example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
The <body> tag is a common tag in html.
</html>
```

the body tag won't show. It just said 'the tag'. HTML thought it is just a normal tag so it won't display. The tutorial would require that explanation. How can I make it display as normal text?

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML Character Codes instead

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
The &lt;body&gt; tag is a common tag in html.
</html>
```